# Building a Numpy array by appending data (without knowing the full size in advance)

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management, numpy-ndarray

I have many files, and each file is read as a matrix of shape `(n, 1000)`, where n may be different from file to file.

I'd like to concatenate all of them into a single big Numpy array. I currently do this:

```
dataset = np.zeros((100, 1000))
for f in glob.glob('*.png'):
    x = read_as_numpyarray(f)    # custom function; x is a matrix of shape (n, 1000)
    dataset = np.vstack((dataset, x))
```

but it is inefficient, since I redefine `dataset` many times by stacking the existing array with the next file that is read.

**How to do this in a better way with Numpy, avoiding that the whole dataset is rewritten in memory many times?**

NB: the final big Numpy array might take 10 GB.

Comment: Use just one `np.vstack(big_list_arrays)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way for appending numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439137/efficient-way-for-appending-numpy-array)

Comment: Congratulations for recognizing that the repeated `vstack` copies the data many times.  This topic has come up many times, and the recommendation is to build the list of arrays first.  List append is relatively fast and avoids all those copies.  Do just one `vstack` at the end.

Comment: @ChrisTang, there's got to be a newer and better duplicate (not that anything has changed in this regard since 2014).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to grow a numpy numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a native `list` of numpy arrays, then [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

The native `list` will multiply ([by ~1.125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195579/what-is-the-resizing-factor-of-lists-in-python)) in size when needed, so not too many reallocations will occur, moreover, it will only hold pointers to scattered (non contiguous in memory) `np.arrays` holding the actual data.

Calling `concatenate` only once will solve your problem.

Pseudocode

```
dataset = []
for f in glob.glob('*.png'):
    x = read_as_numpyarray(f)    # custom function; x is a matrix of shape (n, 1000)
    dataset.append(x)

dataset_np = np.concatenate(dataset)
```

---

Notice `vstack` internally uses `concatenate`.

---

### Edit to address the edited question:

> Let's say the total size of data is 20 GB. When concatenating, the
> system will have to still keep 20 GB (for each individual array) and
> also allocate 20 GB for the new concatenated array, thus requiring 40
> GB of RAM (double of the dataset). How to do this without requiring
> the double of RAM? (Example: is there a solution if we only have 32 GB
> of RAM?)

I would attack this problem first by doing the same as proposed in this current answer, in phases. `dataset_np1 = np.concatenate(half1_of_data)`, `dataset_np2 = np.concatenate(half2_of_data)`, will only need 150% RAM (not 200%). This can be extended recursively at the expense of speed until the limit at which this becomes the proposition in the question. I can only assume the likes of [dask](https://pythondata.com/dask-large-csv-python/) can handle this better, but haven't tested myself.

Just to clarify, after you have dataset_np1 you no longer need the list of all the sharded small arrays, and can free that. Only then you start loading the other half. Thus, you only ever need to hold an extra 50% of the data in memory.

Pseudocode:

```
def load_half(buffer: np.array, shard_path: str, shard_ind: int):
    half_dataset = []
    for f in glob.glob(f'{shard_path}/*.png'):
        x = read_as_numpyarray(f)    # custom function; x is a matrix of shape (n, 1000)
        half_dataset.append(x)

    half_dataset_np = np.concatenate(half_dataset) # see comment *
    buffer[:buffer.shape[0] // 2 * (shard_ind + 1), ...] = half_dataset_np

half1_path = r"half1"  # preprocess the shards to be found by glob or otherwise
half2_path = r"half2"
assert os.path.isdir(half1_path)
assert os.path.isdir(half2_path)

buffer = np.zeros(size_shape)
half1_np = load_half(half1_path, buffer, 0) # only 50% of data temporarily loaded, then freed [can be done manually if needed]
half2_np = load_half(half2_path, buffer, 1) # only 50% of data temporarily loaded, then freed
```

One could (easily, or not so easily) generalize this to quarters, eighths, or recursively any required fraction to reduce memory costs at the expense of speed, with the limit at infinity being the original proposition in the question.

- **Important comment** (see "see comment * in the code):
  One might notice `half_dataset_np = np.concatenate(half_dataset)`
  actually allocates 50% of the dataset, with the other 50% allocated
  in shards, apparently saving us nothing. That is correct, and I could
  not find a way to concat into a buffer.   However, implementing this
  recursively as suggested (and not shown in pseudocode) will save
  memory, as a quarter will only use 2* 25% every time. This is just an
  implementation detail, but I hope the gist is clear.

---

On a different note, another approach would state "what if the dataset is 1000GB"? then no numpy array will do. This is why databases exist, and they can be queried quite efficiently using [tools](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-manage-big-data-with-5-python-libraries-a89ce5eddb02). But again, this is somewhat a research question, and depends heavily on your specific needs. As a *very* uninformed hunch, I would check out [dask](https://dask.org/).

Such libraries will obviously tackle problems like this one as a subset of what they do, and I recommend not implementing these things yourself, as the total time you will spend will much outweigh the time choosing and learning a library.

---

On another different note, I wonder if this really has to be such a huge array, and [maybe a slightly different design or formulation of the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) could alleviate us from this technical issue altogether.

Comment: Let's say the total size of data is 20 GB @Gulzar. Then when running the line `dataset_np = np.concatenate(dataset)`, the system will have to still keep 20 GB (for each individual array) *and also* allocate 20 GB for the new array `dataset_np`, thus requiring 40 GB of RAM. Let's say we have only 32 GB of RAM. How would you do that? (i.e. without needing the double of RAM than the size of dataset)

Comment: @Basj Please see edit. If you think something is still missing, please say so and I will come back to this.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-allocate your array. Loop through the files you want to add up front and add up the amount of data you'll retrieve from each. Then create your `dataset` array with the total size you'll need. Finally loop through the files again inserting the data into the already-allocated array. This will be more efficient than allocating new arrays and copying data from previous files over and over for each additional file.

Alternatively don't build a 10GB array. Consider modifying your operations so that they are compatible on smaller chunks of data and read in more manageable data sets on demand.

Comment: Not an answer - size is not known in advance.

Comment: @Gulzar That's why step 1 is to calculate the size. Nothing in the question precludes being able to do this.

Comment: Looping twice over 10GB... I don't consider this viable. You can't always loop only through metadata, for example if the data comes as a stream. Moreover, if it were possible to get only metadata, this wouldn't be a limitation in the question.

Comment: @Gulzar Opening a file and determining how much data is contained within does not require accessing each byte. The data are .png files as stated in the question.

Comment: Opening 1k+ files is very time consuming even without reading the data, as it goes through the OS, and the files are often not on a local hard drive. I am not convinced this will not much slower than it has to be.

Comment: Even when  the final array size is known, the list append approach of the other answer is competative with this assignment to a preallocated array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the concept of [mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r) here. Numpy has inbuilt support of mmap. I like the way @Gulzar has mentioned the sharding to process your files in chunks. I have not worked with mmap() but if you see their documentation it seems that you don't need to have the whole file in the memory. You can write to it via append modes and you can manipulate it that way. Also, if you are concerned with time constraint for this action, as sharding will keep increasing the processing time, you should consider a distributed computation architecture for this procedure. In that way, you can for example use 10 machines, which each have smaller memories, but appends chunks to the bigger memory. I know this is not a complete answer, that's why, I will provide a few resources in the end which are relevant for the ideas I just mentioned. Also, there are hdf5 and zarr which you can use as an work around for this process.

Algorithmic idea of what I told:
(1) start
(2) parse through files 1 to 10: add them, store as mmap referred object in hard disk.
for all n from 1 to 100:
(3) parse n*10+1 to (n+1)*10 files: add them in memory, append them to the mmap referred object in hard disk.
(4) you got your numpy array stored in memory.
References:
(1) [mmap vs zarr vs hdf5](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/mmap-vs-zarr-hdf5/)
(2) [numpy mmap support](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)
(3) [what is mmap actually](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html)